# Passing extra arguments to things in axes.set( )

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to round up everything in boilerplate things like `axes.set_title` and `axes.set_xlims` into `axes.set()`, but I am having a hard time finding any examples on passing things like title padding into `axes.set`. For instance:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = [1,5,1,4,2]

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(a)
ax.set(ylims = [0,6])
ax.set_title('a)', pad = 10)
```

Which I want to include into `ax.set` in this kind of manner, just for illustration:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = [1,5,1,4,2]

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(a)
ax.set(ylims = [0,6],title='a)',pad=10)
```

But I cannot figure out how to include the title padding in there, is there a way to do so?

Comment: Well, I don't know this one helps, but you can set the title padding globally: ```matplotlib.rcParams['axes.titlepad'] = 10 ```.

Comment: @PèterLeèh thanks, that's a good workaround for now, but not sure I want to do that for all my plots

Comment: Does this help: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/simple_plot.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-simple-plot-py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to use [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = [1,5,1,4,2]

d = { 'set_ylim':[0,6], 
      'set_title':{'label':'a)','pad':10}, 
    }

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(a)

for k,v in d.items(): 
    try: 
        getattr(ax,k)(*v) 
    except AttributeError: 
        getattr(ax,k)(**v)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Since I find that axes.set does not allow for passing extra arguments that one would pass in axes.set_title, I believe this is the most suitable and useful answer - thank you!